# Examples of good phone interview quetions.

Tags: soft-question

My school asked me to prepare some students for maths questions in a phone interview. But this is my first time doing this kind of job and I never had this kind of interview myself so I am a little bit at a loss what to do.

I prepared many students the previous years for face-to-face interviews, so I know the idea is not exactly on the ability of students to solve problems but more on how they react to suggetions from the interviewer. But the lack of blackboard during the phone interview make me unconfortable to prepare questions.

Could you share some typical phone interviews questions? This is for an interview to enter a university with a good reputation, as an undergraduate students in engineering (most likely not a future math major).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted. It is well phrased and polite. If someone needs clarification, I feel like they should comment; and if someone feels that this is not an appropriate question for MSE, then I think they should either vote to close or flag the question.

Comment: I suggest you ask your school officials for some additional clarification, namely what they mean by "math questions."  This could be an actual problem in which they are asked to exhibit comprehension of a fundamental mathematical principle, or it could just be more along the lines of how the interviewee perceives the importance of mathematics in his/her engineering education.

Comment: "Math question" means "solving a math problem" (mostly in preCalculus or Calculus).
 
I am sorry if this question does not meet the requirements of this forum, though I don't see why it is different from some other questions in the forum. Feel free to close it if necessary.